# LZ77. Функция сжатия

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сжатие

Пишу курсовую, но никак не могу найти часть алгоритма сжатия LZ77

Предположим, на дана строка S и размер окна W

Как получить std::list

Если Token

```
class Token {
    public:
        // DON'T DISTURB THE ORDER!!!
        lu  dist;
        BYTE character;
        BYTE length;
        // DON'T DISTURB THE ORDER!!!
    };
```

Можно словами, но лучше кодом.

Прочитал много статей, но никак не понимаю момента с построением суффиксного дерева.

P.S.

Есть агоритм

```
// функция возвращает список блоков 
list<Node> encodeLZ77(string s):
   list<Node> ans = []
   pos = 0
   while pos < s.length:
       offset, length = findMatching(buffer, pos)   // ищем слово в словаре
       shiftBuffer(length + 1)                      // перемещаем скользящее окно
       pos += length
       ans.push({offset, length, s[pos]})           // добавляем в ответ очередной блок
   return ans
```

Но мне не понятны вот эти действия:

```
       offset, length = findMatching(buffer, pos)   // ищем слово в словаре
       shiftBuffer(length + 1)                      // перемещаем скользящее окно
       pos += length
```

Comment: Вроде дубликат, все есть на гите https://github.com/search?q=lz77

Comment: @Andrey вы не читали выше. Код есть. Но он непонятен. Мне интересно именно объяснение кода...

Comment: @Andrey возможно, но я не нашел похожий статей

Comment: Не могли бы вы опубликовать, что у вас получилось в итоге, пожалуйста

Comment: Получился в итоге курсач)